# Drools eval() optimization

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, kie

In this documentation mentioned here ( https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.2.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/ ), there is no optimization details provided for the eval() methods used in the when clause. Let's say callMethod print the input character to the log and blindly returns false.

```
rule "Rule1"
when
    eval( callMethod('r') )
then

 ..
 drools.halt();

end

rule "Rule2"

when
    eval( callMethod('r') )
then

 ..
 drools.halt();

end

rule "Rule3"

when
    eval( callMethod('r') )
then

 ..
 drools.halt();
end

rule "Rule4"

when
    eval( callMethod('r') &&
          callMethod('x')
    )
then

 ..
 drools.halt();
end

rule "Rule5"
when
    eval(callMethod('x')
    )
then
 ..
 drools.halt();
end
```

Why is the engine printing:

```
r //probably from rule 1
r //Rule 4
x //Rule 4 again
```

and not

```
r
r
r
r
x
x
```

What is the optimization technique that drools uses here? Its slightly confusing.

Comment: or even r, r, x, x : if I assume that it caches jus the previous similar results of the eval?

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental idea of the Rete algorithm developed by Dr. Charles L. Forgy in 1979 is the extraction of a network of logical expressions from the components of the left hand sides of production rules.

The consequence is that the evaluation of identical expressions cannot be correlated to their textual appearance within the rule code any more.

Details cannot be explained in this format. Google and research.